# OpenProcess fails in wait_cpu_usage_lower

Tags: pywinauto, windows-server-2019

We're trying to open an Explorer window at a certain path, then wait for being ready. The client is operated trhough `rpyc` thus weird stacktraces. This happens sometimes but in the same test only. This function (`fileman_item_properties`) is intended to open file properties window and it works fine in many different places.

```
    command = f'explorer.exe'
    Timings.slow()

    try:
        Application().start(f'{command} /select,{item}')
        app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=command)
        app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=60, usage_interval=1.0)
```

```
4 Traceback (most recent call last):
265   File "/home/serj/work/mpksoft/te/tests/test_vss_simple.py", line 540, in test_restore_root_share_dirs
266     fileman_restore_item(client, self._share_path, version)
267   File "/home/serj/work/mpksoft/te/lib/host/coreui.py", line 377, in fileman_restore_item
268     host_plugin_load(conn, 'coreui').fileman_restore_item(path, version)
269   File "/home/serj/work/.virtualenvs/te36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpyc/core/netref.py", line 240, in __call__
270     return syncreq(_self, consts.HANDLE_CALL, args, kwargs)
271   File "/home/serj/work/.virtualenvs/te36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpyc/core/netref.py", line 63, in syncreq
272     return conn.sync_request(handler, proxy, *args)
273   File "/home/serj/work/.virtualenvs/te36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpyc/core/protocol.py", line 473, in sync_request
274     return self.async_request(handler, *args, timeout=timeout).value
275   File "/home/serj/work/.virtualenvs/te36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rpyc/core/async_.py", line 102, in value
276     raise self._obj
277 rpyc.core.vinegar/pywintypes._get_exception_class.<locals>.Derived: (87, 'OpenProcess', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
278 
279 ========= Remote Traceback (1) =========
280 Traceback (most recent call last):
281   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 320, in _dispatch_request
282     res = self._HANDLERS[handler](self, *args)
283   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 593, in _handle_call
284     return obj(*args, **dict(kwargs))
285   File ".\windows\coreui.py", line 1285, in fileman_restore_item
286     fileman_item_properties(path)
287   File ".\windows\coreui.py", line 422, in fileman_item_properties
288     app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=60, usage_interval=1.0)
289   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1135, in wait_cpu_usage_lower
290     while self.cpu_usage(usage_interval) > threshold:
291   File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 1110, in cpu_usage
292     h_process = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, 0, self.process)
293 pywintypes.error: (87, 'OpenProcess', 'The parameter is incorrect.')
```

**UPD**

Unfortunately, the below code did not fix the problem. The non-ready process somehow passes through the `connect` with timeout.

```
      Application().start(f'{command} /select,{item}')
        app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=command, title_re=f'.*{base_name}.*', timeout=60)
        app.wait_cpu_usage_lower(threshold=0.5, timeout=60, usage_interval=1.0)
```

BTW, the Explorer window is not yet shown at the moment of error.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `explorer.exe` has not enough time to start. You need to use explicit timeout for `connect()` method:

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(path=command, timeout=10)
```

Another possible case is that already existing `explorer.exe` instance is already running and connect by executable name is intermittent. Please use connect by title then!

```
app = Application(backend='uia').connect(title="Properties", timeout=10)
```

Also maybe standard example in Readme.md helps: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/tree/master#ms-ui-automation-example

Comment: So the error means `app` process is not ready?

Comment: Process is not ready or `explorer.exe` may spawn multiple processes including temporary launcher that may exit while pywinauto method is executing. Please rely on window title where possible. Otherwise you don't know to which process you've connected at the moment.

Comment: Updated the question. Great thanks!

Comment: Reviewing the sources could find that `path` and `title_re` arguments are applied as OR. It worth being noted in docs, because the AND logic seems more common.

Comment: I want to change it to AND logic in next major release. Though I can't promise exact dates for this release. We have pretty big backlog and no full time employees.

Comment: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/issues/1127